# When using a ring light, how do I get rid of the dimmed backround?

Tags: flash, lighting, exposure, overexposure, ring-flash

I just bought a new ring light and I love it! However I would like to use it and still have the backround light up instead of everything going dark. How can I achieve this? P.s I use my iphone 6 and my Canon t5i with a 50mm lens to take my photos.

Comment: Do you have a sample image? That's always helpful.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could use a [fill light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fill_light) from a reflector or another strobe to illuminate the background a bit. Of course, that means additional setup time and expense.
2. You could experiment with extending exposure, at least on the Canon, to reduce the brightness of the ring-light in *comparison* to the background (e.g. increase exposure time so that light keeps entering even after the ring-light has blinked). This can introduce blur in the background, which may or may not be desirable.
3. You could put a neutral density filter on the ring-light itself, or reduce its output if it is variable. If the light did not come with a ND filter, make a hole in a piece of *thin* white cloth or paper for the lens, and cover the light.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few simple things that you could do.

Use another light source to light the background separately from your main light, either another strobe or a hot light (constant) behind your subject facing the background.
-OR-
You can open up your aperture and slow down your shutter speed to allow more ambient light in.